# Angular JS - where should my code go?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, three.js

I'm writing a simple galaxy simulation project (think a much simpler http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/stars/) with AngularJS and Threejs. The use of Angular JS is just so that I can understand how it works, and use it for other projects.

I'm a bit baffled about where a lot of my code should live, however. Since the threejs code is output to a canvas, I'm guessing the code should live in a directive? Or should I be doing most of the processing in the controller, and just adding any DOM-specific code to the directive?

You can see my current attempts at organization here: https://github.com/donnielrt/galaxy/tree/873dba548d8d42820febeb4e69817f2e5fc5333c/app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any DOM manipulation or additional behaviors (code that executes in response to some events) should be in a directive.

All of your view-model code, the model that's needed for the front-end and the functions needed to manipulate the view-model or interact with services should be in the controller(s).

Your should write a service or factory for any portion that interacts with third party (REST) APIs or your own custom service layer code.

You can use a filter to modify some text for display.

You can use a constant or value to store, a constant or a value.

Some JS examples

```
angular.module("testApp",[]).controller("MyCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.scopedVar = "from the controller";
}).value("someObject",{someProp:"someValue"}
).constant("SOMECONST",3.14
).directive("myThing", function(){
  return {
    restrict:"E" // E (element), C (class), M (comment), A (attribute)
    scope:{}, // optional =, &, @
    template: "<div>Some custom directive</div>",
    link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs){
      //do some custom things here to modify the directive element or it's children
    }
  }
}).filter("myFilter",function(input){
   var output=input + "did something";
   return output;
});
```

Some HTML

```
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <my-thing></my-thing>
  {{scopedVar | myFilter}}
</body>
```